# How do you pass around a void pointer between Python and C when writing an extension?

Tags: python, c, cpython

I started on my first Python extension today and was only creating a very small wrapper around a C library as an exercise. As is typical with C libraries, you start of with an initialization function that yields a handler. You can pass that handler to functions and later you pass it to the cleanup function that frees memory.

When I started writing the wrapper I basically wanted to have a way to call each native C function from python. Quickly I hit the problem that I need to return an arbitrary pointer from C to Python only to give it from there to C again in another function. I doesn't matter how it looks as I don't use it in Python, I just store it and pass it around.

So how do you pass around a void pointer between Python and C?

Please note: I know it is not recommended to write such small wrappers using the extension system but rather ctypes and friends. This is just for practice right now.

Comment: Related, for those looking for a solution in Cython: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764048/get-the-value-of-a-cython-pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyLong_FromVoidPtr() and PyLong_AsVoidPtr() can be abused to inject malicious data into your program. I recommend against them.

Python has PyCapsule for exactly that job. Capsules provide a safe way to exchange void ptr between modules or Python space and C space. The capsules are type-safe, too. If you need some example, the socket / ssl modules and pyexpat / _elementtree modules use capsules to exchange CAPI structs.

http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/capsule.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on the security problem of the mentioned functions? I could not find any details regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

After some searching I found the functions [PyLong_AsVoidPtr](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html?highlight=voidptr#PyLong_AsVoidPtr) and [PyLong_FromVoidPtr](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html?highlight=voidptr#PyLong_FromVoidPtr). This yields a nice way to convert between a `void *` and a `PyObject`:

```
# in init function
return PyLong_FromVoidPtr(handle);

# in function using handle
handle = PyLong_AsVoidPtr(python_handle);
```

The one problem now might be how to retrieve `python_handle` from the typical `*args` given to a function:

```
PyObject *python_handle;
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &python_handle);
```

Careful here: The argument given for the `"O"` object must be a pointer to a `PyObject` pointer: `PyObject **`. The `"O"` itself only denotes to pass this `PyObject` through without any handling and converting. And with this, you can pass around any pointers any way you like.

*Note*: I think this solution is not really pretty, because you now have to variables, one that is only needed for a short time.

Comment: It is [perfectly acceptable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your question at the same time as you ask it. That is why `answer your own question` is an option when you ask a question!

Comment: And that's what I did. Is there something wrong? I cannot accept it yet, and I don't want to because someone may have a better alternative.

Comment: For importing `PyLong_*` in Cython, do `cdef extern from "Python.h":
    void* PyLong_AsVoidPtr(object)`, as discussed [here](http://osdir.com/ml/python-cython-devel/2009-10/msg00197.html).