# Get the value of a Cython pointer

Tags: python, c, pointers, cython

I am writing a function that constructs a malloc'd `unsigned char *` array, and then retuns the pointer. In pure Cython or C, this is easy. All you have to do is set a return type on the function, and return the pointer to the array. Done. However, I have reached a point where I need to return a pointer to an array created in Cython, to Python. I know that a pointer is simply the memory address. Is there any way that I can return a Cython pointer to Python as a python object (such as int or hex, because the memory address is essentially a number), so I can then basically manage pointers in python?

I have tried to return the value of the pointer like this:

```
cdef unsigned char array[8]

def return_pointer():
    return &array
```

This of course does not work because the conversion cant be done. Cython complains with `Cannot convert 'unsigned char (*)[8]' to Python object`. Any suggestions?

*EDIT:*

I do not need to access the value in the memory address referenced by the pointer in Python, only pass the pointer around. I then plan to use the Python object pointer, and call c functions with it as an argument.

Comment: There are several options for that, any which one (*if any*) is right depends a lot on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well does my function present a specific example that can be narrowed down?

Comment: No, the alternatives all start from a pointer. As in, your function can equally easily be turned into any of them. By the way, your example function is wrong. It returns a pointer to a local which is deallocated after the return, and it creates a pointer to the whole array (type `unsigned char (*)[N]`) instead of coercing it to a pointer to the first element (type `unsigned char *`) which is by far more customary and useful though it's technically the same address in the end.

Comment: Ok I edited the local array, but the problem is, is that when I do make a unsigned char pointer to the first element and return it, Python looks at it as if it was a string and prints random memory. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, that's one alternative, and apparently it's not what you want. You can also turn the pointer into an `int`, you can construct `ctypes` pointers, you can perhaps even create `cffi` pointers, etc. and unless you explain what you're trying to do nobody can help you with deciding which is right.

Comment: Simply to a python int object so it can be passed around in python.

Comment: Not accessed though, I do not want to access the value at the pointer from python.

Comment: im using `<long>somePointer` to get value

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can cast a pointer to the appropriate C type, which should then be translated into a Python integer by Cython. The correct C type is `uintptr_t` from `<stddef.h>` which in Cython would be available via `from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t`. The cast is of course written `<uintptr_t>array_or_pointer`.

Comment: Perfect, and this also allows me to cast a uintptr_t type from python to an array of unsigned chars. This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Great answer, just a tiny correction regarding the import. It should be `cimport` instead of `import` in order to work.

Comment: @sirfz Thanks, fixed.

Comment: How do I the converse and convert the integer back to a pointer?

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad You would need to cast your integer back to the appropriate pointer type. In the OP's question which dealt with characters, that would mean doing `<char *>my_uintptrs_name`.

Comment: Is there any way to cast floats rather than int like that? It seems that float.pxd (https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/float.pxd) does not import a pointer type